# Sister color scheme in SASS

Tags: css, variables, sass

Does anyone know if there is an easier way to do the following:

```
$blue: #336699;
$pink: #B5D09B;

body .primary-scheme {

  .box {
    background: $blue;

    .secondary-scheme & {
      background: $pink;
    }
  }

  .box2 {
    border: 1px solid $blue;

    .secondary-scheme & {
      border: 1px solid $pink;
    }

  }
}
```

I have an existing website, and need to make a sister website with different colours. I want to try and find a better way of replacing the color for each element but can't myself.

Comment: What's wrong with this? I'd use the same code - but I'd rename the colors.

Comment: @Vucko I've used a general example as I don't want to put my code in here. I have loads of references where I need to change the color, so want to see if there is a better way I can do it, rather than changing borders, backgrounds etc to the sister color everytime.

Comment: I doubt there's a better way. Just rename the variables to `$color1, $color2 etc.` (or something else) and put the name of the color in a comment . `$color1: #336699; //blue`. That way you have to only change the HEX value of the color, and the color name in the comment.

Comment: do you add "secondary-scheme" to the sister website?

Comment: @riddy I don't necessarily need the "primary-scheme" class but I do put the "secondary-scheme" class on the body to overrite the styles.

Comment: oaky.. why don't you compile the theme once with "$blue: #336699;" and then again with "$blue: #B5D09B;" or did I understood this wrong?